# Randomly add a LETTER in different files

Tags: r, cat

I have some .txt files and I need to randomly add LETTERS in each one of them.  I'm trying this function **for** with no results.

Is there a better way to approach this?

```
files<-list.files(path=MyDir.,pattern=".txt",full.names = T)

for(f in files){
  letter<-sample(LETTERS,1)
  cat(letter,file = f )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I need to randomly add LETTERS in each one of the files*?  Add to the actual file or just the file name?  This is not clear

Comment: Add to the actual file, i have in MyDir these files : 1.txt,2.txt,3.txt,...,100.txt, what kind of function cai i use to do that ?

Comment: Can you tell us specifically what's happening/what's not working? `cat(letter,"\n",file=f,append=TRUE)` seems to work OK for me.

Comment: There is no error or warning showing in R, but when I open the files (1.txt,2.txt...100.txt) they're empty

Comment: have you tried my modification?

Comment: Still not working.  'files<-list.files(path="exercicio03",pattern=".txt",full.names = T)
for(f in files){
  
  letra<-sample(LETTERS,1)
  
  cat(letra,"\n",file=f,append=TRUE)
  
}'

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 # Make some fake files
  for(i in 1:3){
    write(x = c(), file = paste0(i,".txt") )
  }

 # Store the name of the files       
  ( files <- list.files(path=getwd(),pattern=".txt",full.names = T))

  # Iterate over the file names and add a letter 
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    fileConn<-file(files[i])
    writeLines(sample(LETTERS,1), fileConn)
    close(fileConn)
  }
```